# JS divide percent % discount from sum

Tags: javascript, calculator

how do I divide % from amount? I mean I want js to calculate discounted price, for example I have this:

```
var voucherdiscount='23';
var amount = ((qty*price) - voucherdiscount + %); it is wrong what is the right way?
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is JavaScript's [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_%28.25%29), and is used for calculating the remainder of a division

```
13 % 4; // 1
```

This can be read as "13 divided by 4 equals 3 with a remainder of `1`"

**Additional note:** In most languages, this is called the "modulus operator", but JavaScript implements it a bit differently. See [this note](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3amodulo_operator) for more details.

---

You can calculate the total price like this

```
qty * price * (1 - voucherdiscount/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amount = Qty*price
23% of amount -> (amount*23)/100

Total price: (qty*price) - (qty*price*discount)/100